# Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a string cell Apache POI

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, apache-poi

I copy and pasted the code from this baeldung tutorial.

```
    package aaanalysis;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    
    public class ExcelPOIHelper {
        
        public Map<Integer, List<String>> readExcel(String fileLocation) throws IOException {
            
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(fileLocation));
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    
            Map<Integer, List<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
            int i = 0;
            for (Row row : sheet) {
                data.put(i, new ArrayList<String>());
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
                        case STRING: 
                            data.get(new Integer(i)).add(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                        case NUMERIC:  
//This is where the error is    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                            data.get(i).add(cell.getDateCellValue() + "");
                        } else {
                            data.get(i).add(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "");
                        };
                        case BOOLEAN:  
                            data.get(i).add(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "");
                        case FORMULA:  
                            data.get(i).add(cell.getCellFormula() + "");
                        default: data.get(new Integer(i)).add(" ");
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            return data;
        }
        public void writeExcel() throws IOException {
            //create workbook
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    
            //create sheet and set column widths
            Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Persons");
            sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 6000);
            sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 4000);
            
            //create header row
            Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
    
            //Create style for the header
            CellStyle headerStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            headerStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_BLUE.getIndex());
            headerStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    
            //Set the font for the headerStyle
            XSSFFont font = ((XSSFWorkbook) workbook).createFont();
            font.setFontName("Arial");
            font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 16);
            font.setBold(true);
            headerStyle.setFont(font);
    
            //Adding data to the sheet
            Cell headerCell = header.createCell(0);
            headerCell.setCellValue("Name");
            headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
    
            headerCell = header.createCell(1);
            headerCell.setCellValue("Age");
            headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
            
            CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
            style.setWrapText(true);
    
            Row row = sheet.createRow(2);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue("John Smith");
            cell.setCellStyle(style);
    
            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(20);
            cell.setCellStyle(style);
            
            File currDir = new File(".");
            String path = currDir.getAbsolutePath();
            String fileLocation = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1) + "temp.xlsx";
    
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
        }
    }
```

This is the unit test

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import aaanalysis.ExcelPOIHelper;

public class ExcelTest {
    private ExcelPOIHelper excelPOIHelper;
    private static String FILE_NAME = "temp.xlsx";
    private String fileLocation;

    @Before
    public void generateExcelFile() throws IOException {
        File currDir = new File(".");
        String path = currDir.getAbsolutePath();
        fileLocation = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1) + FILE_NAME;

        excelPOIHelper = new ExcelPOIHelper();
        excelPOIHelper.writeExcel();
    }

    @Test
    public void whenParsingPOIExcelFile_thenCorrect() throws IOException {
        Map<Integer, List<String>> data = excelPOIHelper.readExcel(fileLocation);

        assertEquals("Name", data.get(0).get(0));
        assertEquals("Age", data.get(0).get(1));

        assertEquals("John Smith", data.get(1).get(0));
        assertEquals("20", data.get(1).get(1));
    }
}
```

Also as a point to notice, when adding to the sheet, the row right after the header was skipped and went straight to the second row although the assert don't seem to matchup. What seems to be the issue going on here. Other answers don't seem to be solving the issue.

Comment: Your `switch` ... `case` lacks all `break` statements. 

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html: "...The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall through..."

Comment: Can you please make your question more clear? What are you trying to achieve and where is the problem? You need to get an Integer value from a STRING cell which content represents a number?

Comment: It was the missing break statements.